# Robotium Recording failed after click on New Robotium Test button

Tags: android-studio, robotium-recorder

I have installed the Robotium recorder plugin in Android studio and tried to record some steps by clicking on New Robotium Test button. As per the steps, I have included my APK in the file path destination. When I click on new Robotium test, the APK gets installed properly on the emulator but then it shows the following message:

`Recording failed. Please see output C:\Users\admins\Robotium_log.txt`

Following is the text file of `Robotium_log.txt`. When i open it displays the text as shown below:

> Input:
>
> E:\Jink\jink-mvp-android\gradlew.bat -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
>   assembleDebugAndroidTest -u -b
>   E:\Jink\jink-mvp-android\executorproject\build.gradle
>
> Output:
>
> Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but
>   primary configuration failure takes precedence.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: SDK location not found. Define location
>   with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME
>   environment variable.     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.getAndCheckSdkFolder(SdkHandler.java:140)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.getSdkLoader(SdkHandler.java:150)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:118)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.java:684)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:621)
>     at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:571)
>     at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:568)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:567)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:564)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:628)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:129)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38) BUILD FAILED   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   Total time: 3.824 secs    at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)  FAILURE: Build failed with
>   an exception.  * Where: Build file
>   'E:\Jink\jink-mvp-android\executorproject\build.gradle' line: 54  *
>   What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project
>   'executorproject'. > SDK location not found. Define location with
>   sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME
>   environment variable.  * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the
>   stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.